# TFS Prevent two people from editing the same bug

Tags: tfs, tfs-2013

I am working on an evaluation of TFS 2013, specifically for bug tracking.  We are already using it for source control. The question that has been asked, is regarding the "locking" of bug records in TFS.  Our folks have demonstrated that they can get into a state where if using the web client, and Visual Studio, they are able to both edit the same bug.

Is there a way to limit this interaction so that only one person can edit that item?  I know other bug tracking software already does this.  I am hoping that this is a misconfiguration in the proto environment that they have built.

Comment: do you want to set only one specific user can edit bugs? Or you don't want bugs be modified by more than one users at the same time? It is better if you can give us one example to show the scenario.

Comment: Don't want bugs modified by more than one user...

Comment: Here is the scenario...  Large functional teams of QA, POs, and Devs...  QA enters a bug, saves it.  Comes back, starts to add clarification.  At the same time, Dev starts to mark it up asking for more information.  PO sees the item and starts adding comments as well.  It becomes a race to who can commit first.  How can I prevent this in software?  Other test management software prevents this out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid multiple modification on a work item at the same time, you can customize the "Changed By" Field definition to prevent others to modify this field once it has a value:

```
<FieldDefinition name="Changed By" refname="System.ChangedBy" type="String" syncnamechanges="true" reportable="dimension">
<COPY from="currentuser" />  
<FROZEN /> 
</FieldDefinition>
```

Check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404857.aspx

Comment: The question is about editing/locking work items not source code.

Comment: @ds19 Editing/locking a work item requires a change to the work item template, which is XML code.  By default, this restriction is not in place and it requires modifying the template.

Comment: @Sumo initial answer was about allowing multiple check-out (see answer's history)